# Get credit for your participation in Private Beta!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, badges

Your once in a life time opportunity to get the *silver* badge for participating in Private Beta, is no longer obtainable after the private beta period ends (7-21 days).

The requirements are:

- 3 posts with a net score > 0,
- Vote 10 times,
- Visited the site on 3 separate days,
- (All of the above need to be completed before the 7-21 day private beta period ends).

[27 users](https://drones.stackexchange.com/help/badges/30/beta) got this badge in the last Private Beta to go public (Drones SE). I hope to see a lot of these awarded for us as well!

---

<sup>Credit: This post was almost entirely taken from [here](https://drones.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26/get-your-beta-badge-now).</sup>

Comment: From the [help page](https://materials.stackexchange.com/help/badges) you need three posts (not questions) with score > 0. Not that it matters much.

Comment: I'm assuming this shows up when the private beta ends?

Comment: @GeoffHutchison, yes! The badge called "Beta" is only given once the Private Beta is approved to go to Public Beta.

Comment: "*Asked 19 days ago*" - So I guess it's too late now to try to get it, since I cannot visit the site in 3 days before the 21 days period ends. BTW, was it extended from 14 to 21 days?

Comment: @stafusa Thank you so much for all your participation! As for how long it takes to graduate from Private Beta into Public Beta, originally we thought it was 7-14 days (which was indeed the case for the last site that went Public), but we received news on the 13th day that our Public launch would have to wait until 19 May (tomorrow), which is 21 days. That makes it hard for someone that joined today, to get the Private Beta badge, but even harder for all the thousands of people that didn't find out about the site yet. But I still wouldn't mind arguing a case (to the CMs) for you to get a badge.

Comment: That's very nice of you, @NikeDattani, but you don't need to worry, I'll probably not make 3 posts that soon either, and badges are anyway not my (main ;)) motivation.

Comment: I think it's quite unlikely that they would try to hack some code to hand out badges in these very exceptional circumstances like this (99.99% of the eventual users will not be getting the badge, since many of them might not have even been born early enough to participate in the Beta, and of the remaining 0.1%: 99% will get the badge because they joined in the first 18 days (not during days 19, 20, and 21). There's a user that has a fanatic badge on every site because he has a bot that signs into every site everyday, so it looks like he visits 100 days in a row: but the badge isn't taken away.

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations to the [**34 users** that got the silver Beta badge](https://materials.stackexchange.com/help/badges/30/beta)! Thank you so much for your contributions !!!